# How to change image of dynamic list?

Tags: android

I have dynamic listview which contain 1 imageview and 1 textview.
My problem is I have to change the image of particular position in onclick
Here is my code

```
public class CoverLetterAdaptor extends BaseAdapter
{
    String[] coverLetterItems;
    Context context;    
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;   
    int ht,wt;

public CoverLetterAdaptor(Context context,int ht,int wt, String[] coverLetterTitle)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.coverLetterItems = coverLetterTitle ;          
    this.ht = ht;
    this.wt = wt;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return coverLetterItems.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.coverletteradaptor, null);     
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.coverLetterTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.coverLetterAdaptorTxt);
        holder.bgImageCCAdaptor = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bgimageCoverLetter);
        holder.bgimageCoverLetter = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.bgimageCoverLetterr);
        holder.bgimageCoverLetter.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(wt, ht/7));       
        convertView.setTag(holder);
     }
    else                
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.coverLetterTxt.setText(coverLetterItems[position]);

    return convertView;
} 

static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView coverLetterTxt;        
    ImageView bgImageCCAdaptor;
    ImageView bgimageCoverLetter;
}

}
```

Pls help me
Thanks

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: In your getview you have not set any image so how do you change the image you can only set not change correct me if I am wrong

Comment: do u want to switch images or want to change it to any random image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement an [OnItemclicklistener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) and then react to [Itemclicks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29). Use this method to change the source of the bitmap then.

It works now with the above method. here is the code.

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adaptview, View clickedview, int position,
                long id) {

            //TEST SO 4533684
            View subview = clickedview.findViewById(R.id.bgimageCoverLetter);
            ((ImageView) subview).setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
            //END TEST 
        }
```